# check last part of URL with php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working with Zend Framework. I want to check last part of link. my link is `http://localhost/sports/soccer/page_id/776543233242`

my last part of URL must have 12 or 11 digit , and I want first of that part start with 8 if 11 digit and start with 7 if 12 digit.

```
public function detailAction ()
{

    $uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
     if (substr(substr($uri, -12),1)=='7'){
        echo "successfull";
     }
     else if (substr(substr ($uri , -11),8)=='0'){
        echo "succ";
     }
     else {
        echo "failed";
     }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to grab: `776543233242` and validate this ?

Comment: Actually I want to compare with other string , but in this step , yes , just validate this substring.@Rizier123

Comment: I hope my answer helps you and it is what you want

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

       $url = "http://localhost/sports/soccer/page_id/776543233242";
       $part = basename($url);

       if(strlen($part) == 11 && $part[0] == 8 || strlen($part) == 12 && $part[0] == 7)
            echo "yes";
        else
            echo "no";

?>
```

Output:

```
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `basename()` function in php to get your last part of the url and then count the string.Check the no of word using `strlen`. Use the code below

```
    public function detailAction ()
{

    $url = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
           $url = "http://localhost/sports/soccer/page_id/776543233242";
           $basename = basename($url);

           if(strlen($basename) == 11 && $basename[0] == 8 || strlen($basename) == 12 && $basename[0] == 7){
                echo "succ";
    }
            else{
                echo "failed";
    }
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Why does that seems to be so similar to my answer?!

Comment: Oh.. Its almost like your answer , i didn't noticed it, bye the way +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

See [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url). You can then get the path and split it on `/`.

```
function isValidUrl($url)
{
    $elements = parse_url($url);

    if ($elements === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $lastItem = end(explode("/", $elements['path']);
    return ((strlen($lastItem) == 12 && $lastItem[0] == '7') || (strlen($lastItem) == 11 && $lastItem[0] == '8'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the number form your url I suggest you to use regex. in this case:

```
$url="http://localhost/sports/soccer/page_id/776543233242";
$regex = "/[0-9]+/";
preg_match_all($regex, $url, $out); //$out will be an array storing the mathcing strings, preg_match_all creates this variable to us
var_dump($out);
```

This code outputs the `$out`. It will look like this:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
        string(12) "776543233242"
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the part of the url desired corresponds to the `page_id` parameter.

With Zend Framework, you can do something like this to get the value of this parameter:

```
$page_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');

if(strlen($page_id) == 11 && $page_id[0] == 8 
|| strlen($page_id) == 12 && $page_id[0] == 7)
    echo "yes";
else
    echo "no";
```